# Chaotic monochromatic light

Tags: optics, laser, correlation-functions, coherence, light-emitting-diodes

I am currently reading through the book "The Quantum Theory of Light", by Rodney Loudon, in order to prepare for a science fair project which will involve measuring plant response to coherent and incoherent sources of light. Along the way, I have run into problem 3.1 in the book, which reads as follows:

> Consider a one-dimensional cavity that contains a chaotic light beam, and suppose that all the cavity-mode contributions to the field except one are removed by means of a filter. The mode that remains has a large number of contributions similar to the stable wave of Fig. 3.8, all with the same frequency and wavevector but with a random distribution of phase angles. Prove that the beam is first-order coherent at any pair of space-time points in the cavity.

After thinking about it for a while, though, I just don't see how this could be the case. If we use the "interrupted wave-train" model of chaotic light from earlier in this chapter, it seems to me that every $\tau_c$ seconds or so (where $\tau_c$ is the coherence time) the shifting of the phase angle should cause the correlation function $\langle E^*(t_1)E(T_2)\rangle$ to go to $0$ by definition. So how can it be that the books claims such a source will be coherent?

Secondly, on a more practical note, I'm curious just how monochromatic a chaotic beam of light needs to be in order to exhibit coherence. In order to investigate the response of plants to incoherent light, for instance, I was planning on using some red LEDs that claim they have a spectral range of 620-625 nm. That's quite narrow, but not *exactly* monochromatic, so how would I estimate the degree of first-order coherence for a source like that?

Comment: You have to distinguish the temporal coherence from the spectral coherence. In the latter respect the radiation may be incoherent (if you have wide frequency range contributing) but it still may be temporally coherent. See my web page https://www.physicsmyths.org.uk/fourier.htm for more.

Comment: And does the reverse hold? Would a narrowband LED still be temporally incoherent at waiting times greater than $\tau_c$?

Comment: I am not familiar with LEDs and the physical processes of relevance here. But given that these are solid state materials, it is unlikely the atomic decay times are anything as long as in a gaseous plasma. In fact, given the spectral range you quoted, this would be of the order of magnitude consistent with the collision frequency in solid state materials, so the spectral coherence would reflect the temporal coherence in this case. From the spectral Fourier transform relationship $\Delta\omega\cdot\Delta t=1/2$ this would mean the LED has a temporal coherence of about $\Delta t=10^{-13} sec$

Comment: Note that the temporal coherence of the LED light would therefore actually be considerably  *less* than the light of a gaseous discharge lamp or even sunlight! As shown on my already quoted web page https://www.physicsmyths.org.uk/fourier.htm (which basically confirms your book quotation) the temporal coherence is not necessarily related to the spectral width but only has to do with the atomic decay and collision frequencies in the physical medium producing the light. This is what you should consider (unless of course you actually *want* to examine the effect of spectral bandwidth)

Comment: Which version of the book do you have? I have the 3rd edition (from 2000) and there the problem refers to figure 3.10, which is simply a monochromatic wave. That makes the problem much clearer.

Comment: @A.P.: I have the second edition